# MATLAB cannot load file

Tags: matlab

I was using trying an example to train a *cascade object detector* found in this link :

[Train a cascade object detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html#btuo74_)

and tried to use this command : `load('stopSigns.mat');`

However, for some reason it is saying : *Unable to read file stopSigns.mat: No such file or directory*.

Does someone know if I am missing something?

P.S.: I have the Computer Vision Toolbox in Simulink

Comment: Thanks Luis for your response...So where can I find such file...in Matlab Root

Comment: Using Spotlight to search, the path on my system is `[matlabroot '/toolbox/vision/visiondemos/']`.

Comment: @horchler I went to that path manually however I only found these two mat files : 1). stereoPointPairs.mat and 2). yellowstone_matched_points.mat...Does this mean the toolbox was not installed correctly?

Comment: @user2541516: That, or you're looking at the documentation for the current version of the toolbox, but are using an older version that might not have that demo or that might have a different directory structure. Type `visiondemos` in your command window to see the documentation for the demos in your version (assuming things are installed properly).

Comment: Yes @hochler, that was the problem. I was reading the documentation for R2014a, when I have MATLAB R2012b.  Do you suggest that I buy R2014a or it is enough to have the older version, in order to train an object detector?

Comment: @user2541516: No idea. That seems like a separate question and I'm not familiar with object detectors or much or the vision toolbox.